# GSAP animation not working with $ref in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, gsap

I am having an issue with a GSAP animation in a Nuxt build. The animation is to start when the
overlay navigation panel is brought into view with `v-if="isMenuOpen"`. The nav works and shows as expected, but I want to animate the different items within the nav. The problem is GSAP isn't finding the items to animate. I've tried different approaches:

1. using `TL.fromTo('.nav__panel-nav ul li a', {` but this returns the error `GSAP target .nav__panel-nav ul li a not found.`
2. using `TL.fromTo(this.$refs.li, {` on both the components and wrapping HTML `li` element, which returns the error `GSAP target undefined not found.`

I'm new to working with Vue/Nuxt so i'm not sure o the best way to rectify the issue. Any direction on how to get this working, or a better approach would be appreciated.

```html
<template>
  <transition name="card">
    <div class="nav" v-if="isMenuOpen">
      <div class="nav__panel">
        <div class="nav__panel-inner">
          <div class="nav__panel-contact">
            <div class="h-3">Contact Us</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">xxx</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav__panel-social">
              <SocialLinks />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav__panel">
        <div class="nav__panel-inner">
          <nav class="nav__panel-nav">
            <ul>
              <li ref="li">
                <NuxtLink to="/" ref="test">Home</NuxtLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/about-us">About Us</NuxtLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/our-expertise">Our Expertise</NuxtLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NuxtLink to="/contact-us">Contact Us</NuxtLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import { gsap } from "gsap";

export default {

  computed: {

    isMenuOpen() {
      return this.$store.getters['navState'];
    }

  },

  watch: {

    isMenuOpen(val) {
      if (val) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('no-scroll');
        this.animateNavIn();
      } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.remove('no-scroll');
        this.animateNavOut();
      }
    }

  },

  methods: {

    animateNavIn() {
      // https://blog.logrocket.com/animating-vue-with-greensock/

      console.log('animate in');

      const TL = gsap.timeline();

      // TL.fromTo('.nav__panel-nav ul li a', {
      TL.fromTo(this.$refs.li, {
        duration: 1,
        autoAlpha: 1,
        y: '15px',
        stagger: 0.05,
        ease: "Power2.out"
      },
      {
        autoAlpha: 1,
        y: 0,
      })

      .to('.nav__panel-contact .h-3, li, .social__title, .social__links', { 
        duration: 1,
        autoAlpha: 1,
        y: 0,
        stagger: 0.05,
        ease: "Power2.out"
      }, '-=.9');
  
    },

    animateNavOut() {

      console.log('animate out');

      // const TL = gsap.timeline();

      // TL.to('.nav__panel-nav ul li a', {
      //   duration: 1,
      //   autoAlpha: 1,
      //   y: 0,
      //   stagger: 0.05,
      //   ease: "Power2.out"
      // });
 
    }

  },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've worked out what part of the issue is. The problem was with using `v-if` to render the nav. By using this, the elements I was trying to target weren't in the DOM so they couldn't be found. My solution was to use `v-show` instead. The difference is that an element with v-show will always be rendered and remain in the DOM; v-show only toggles the display CSS property of the element.

I am now able to target the HTML `a` tags using GSAP. I'm still not sure why `$refs` wouldn't work though...